# Can someone please explain "Repeated column in mapping for entity"?

Tags: java, hibernate

I keep getting error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
> net.tekknow.moneymachine.model.Quote column: date (should be mapped
> with insert="false" update="false")"

no matter what I try.

Here is my Quote class:

```
public class Quote {
    @EmbeddedId
    private QuoteId quoteId;    //composite id needed by hibernate
    
    private String symbol;
    private Date date;
    private float close;
 
    public Quote() {}
    public Quote(String symbol, Date date, float close) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.date = date;
        this.close = close;
    }
    public QuoteId getId() {
        return quoteId;
    }
    public void setId(QuoteId id) {
        this.quoteId = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "symbol", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @Column(name = "date", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
... //other getters and setters
```

Here is QuoteId class which is supposed to be needed by Hibernate to join two columns as a composite key per https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

```
@Embeddable
public class QuoteId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "symbol", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String symbol;
    
    @Column(name = "date", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date date;
    
    public QuoteId(String symbol, Date date) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.date = date;
    }
    public QuoteId() {}
    
    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    ...    // other getters and setters
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        QuoteId that = (QuoteId) o;
        return Objects.equals(symbol, that.symbol) && Objects.equals(date, that.date);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(symbol, date);
    }   
}
```

Hoping you experts can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `QuoteId` class is marked as `@Embeddable` which means that a database table for `Quote` pulls in all columns from `QuoteId` in addition to its own columns.

Becuse you have a column with name `date` (and, by the way, `symbol` too) in both tables, you end up with a table definition which has two columns with the same name, which is not allowed.

If you are trying to use a composite key for `Quote`, you need to remove `date` and `symbol` from `Quote`. Note that this is **not** joining two tables, as there will be no `QuoteId` as a separate table.

Comment: That totally makes sense.  Thank you so much for helping me understand!